# mongokit No collection found

Tags: python, mongodb, mongokit

I'm using mongokit with flask, and everytime I try to use a collection I created, I receive the error `No collection found`

I defined my collections in a separated file models.py. It looks like this:

```
from mongokit import Connection, Document
import os
import sys

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(here, 'settings'))
sys.path.append(path)
from settings import base as settings

connection = Connection()

@connection.register
class Contact(Document):
    __database__ = settings.MONGO_DBNAME
    __collection__ = "Contact"

    structure = {
        "name":unicode,
        "mobile_number":unicode,
    }

    required_fields = ["name"]


@connection.register
class User(Document):
    __database__ = settings.MONGO_DBNAME
    __collection__ = 'User'

    structure = {
        "username":unicode,
        "twitter_access_token":unicode,
        "twitter_token_secret":unicode,
        "contacts":[Contact]
    }
    required_fields = ["username"]
    default_values = {
            "twitter_access_token": "",
            "twitter_token_secret": ""
        }
```

But then I tried:

```
>>> from models import User
>>> u = User()
>>> u["username"] = "somename"
>>> u.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/fernandocezar/.virtualenvs/contacts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongokit/document.py", line 404, in save
    self.validate(auto_migrate=False)
  File "/Users/fernandocezar/.virtualenvs/contacts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongokit/document.py", line 230, in validate
    (size_limit, size_limit_str) = self._get_size_limit()
  File "/Users/fernandocezar/.virtualenvs/contacts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongokit/document.py", line 214, in _get_size_limit
    server_version = tuple(self.connection.server_info()['version'].split("."))
  File "/Users/fernandocezar/.virtualenvs/contacts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongokit/document.py", line 622, in __getattribute__
    raise ConnectionError('No collection found') 
mongokit.mongo_exceptions.ConnectionError: No collection found
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/tutorial.html), but not even the notation `connection.<dbname>.<collection>()` works. And yes, there is, indeed, such a collection.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the [tutorial](http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/tutorial.html) you linked:

> To avoid repeating ourselves though, let’s specify the database and
>   collection name in the Document definition:
>
> ```
> @connection.register
> class BlogPost(Document):
>     __collection__ = 'blog_posts'
>     __database__ = 'blog'
>     structure = {...}
>
> >>> bp = connection.BlogPost()
> ```

In the shell example, the model object is constructed through the `connection` object. In your case, you were simply doing `user = User()`. Try creating the user through the same `connection` instance that you used to register the model (e.g. `user = connection.User()`).

Comment: Not really. `connection.User()`, as well as connection.contacts.User() returns the following error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/fernandocezar/.virtualenvs/contacts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 769, in __call__
    self.__name, self.__connection.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'User' method on a 'Connection' object it is failing because no such method exists.`

Comment: Perhaps this is because the model was registered to a different `Connection` instance than the one you're referencing in the shell? I just created a new script using the tutorial and was able to yield your error if the connections were not the same.